# Create new keys array with certain order conditions on foreach php

Tags: php, arrays

i have multidimensional arrays, i want to create new lines in the foreach that I made with by checking `[delivery_indicator] == 0`

my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_line_no] => 0001
            [delivery_indicator] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_line_no] => 0002
            [delivery_indicator] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_line_no] => 0003
            [delivery_indicator] => 1
        )
)
```

this is the code that I made to create new array

```
 foreach($po as $key => $i){
    if($i['delivery_indicator'] === '0'){
       $po[] = array(); /* create new array */
    }                 
 }
```

a new array will be created but at the end of the array. 
How to make new array just below the array that has `[delivery indicator] = 0`?

the results that I expected

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emp_order_no] => xxx-002
            [item_line_no] => 0001
            [delivery_indicator] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
         /* new array */
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [emp_order_no] => xx-002
            [item_line_no] => 0002
            [delivery_indicator] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
         /* new array */
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [emp_order_no] => xxx-001
            [item_line_no] => 0003
            [delivery_indicator] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
$po[] = array(); /* create new array */
```

this is adding it to the end of the array, to add it in the next slot, it may be easier to copy the data...

```
$output = [];
foreach($po as $key => $i){
    $output[] = $i;
    if($i['delivery_indicator'] === '0'){
        $output[] = array(); /* create new array */
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code adds a new array with the content of `test` after your array that has the key `delivery_indicator` equal to `0`. Be careful with the `===` indicator. It works with an for loop and not with foreach because the array is constantly changing. The array_splice function adds the new array at the position right after the actual index.

```
for( $index = 0; $index < count( $po ); $index++ )  {
  if(isset($po[$index]['delivery_indicator']) && $po[$index]['delivery_indicator'] === '0'){
     array_splice( $po, $index + 1, 0, array( array( 'test' ) ) );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emp_order_no] => xxx-002
            [item_line_no] => 0001
            [delivery_indicator] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [emp_order_no] => xx-002
            [item_line_no] => 0002
            [delivery_indicator] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [emp_order_no] => xxx-001
            [item_line_no] => 0003
            [delivery_indicator] => 1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are starting with 
$po = Array....

```
$pa = [];
 foreach($po as $key => $i){
    if($i['delivery_indicator'] === '0'){
       $i[emp_order_no] = "xxx-002" // Just guessing how is this filled
       $pa[]= $i;
       $pa[]= [];// new array, different syntax, same result
    }else{
       $i[emp_order_no] = "xxx-001" // Just guessing how is this filled
       $pa[]= $i;
    }    
 } 
 $po = $pa; // optional unset($pa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is also that you are strict comparing literals to numbers.
you stated:

```
if($i['delivery_indicator'] === '0'){// string
```

but you have:

```
        [delivery_indicator] => 0 // number
```

Besides the logic I mean

Comment: You can edit your first answer and add this information to it.

Comment: Is that the intended usage? I mean, the 2 solutions are completely different and no related. Thats why I did it separately. I even though of editing his question